# Change the tag in the return section in wordpress gutenburg block by condition

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I want to change the tag in a save section using if condition.

I have created the block and return like this

```
return <a className={`card-item ` + className} href={cta_link} style={{backgroundColor: panel_colour}}>
------------
----
</a>
```

Now i want to change the anchor tag "" to "" by if condition. like

```
if ( cta_link )
<a className={`card-item ` + className} href={cta_link} style={{backgroundColor: panel_colour}}>
else
<div className={`card-item ` + className} style={{backgroundColor: panel_colour}}>
```

and also the closing tag. so is there any best way to do that ? i am new in the gutenburg block. Please let me know to enhance my knowledge.

Thank you

Comment: I don't think it's advisable; I think you'd want to use separate blocks, otherwise you'd be looking at writing logic in both the edit and save methods of the block's react-component. Why not transform between two different blocks? Have you reviewed the documentation? https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-edit-save/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this pattern a lot when I have a block with an optional link:

```js
save: ( { attributes } ) => {
    const { url } = attributes;

    // If this block has a url, make it a link, otherwise make it a div.
    const Component = url !== '' ? 'a' : 'div';
    
    return (
        <Component></Component>
    );
}
```